Unable to run biber with a recent version of TeX Live
When I run biber --help, I get the following error message:
$ biber --help

Number found where operator expected (Do you need to predeclare "POSIX::_exit"?) at /tmp/par-6a6f736875612e68796b6573/cache-8e80c9c14f39e44498a1091586b807a0d
52ef04a/inc/lib/IPC/Cmd.pm line 622, near "POSIX::_exit 1"
Bareword "POSIX::WNOHANG" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /tmp/par-6a6f736875612e68796b6573/cache-8e80c9c14f39e44498a1091586b807a0d52ef04a/inc/lib/
IPC/Cmd.pm line 502.
syntax error at /tmp/par-6a6f736875612e68796b6573/cache-8e80c9c14f39e44498a1091586b807a0d52ef04a/inc/lib/IPC/Cmd.pm line 622, near "POSIX::_exit 1"
Execution of /tmp/par-6a6f736875612e68796b6573/cache-8e80c9c14f39e44498a1091586b807a0d52ef04a/inc/lib/IPC/Cmd.pm aborted due to compilation errors.
Compilation failed in require at script/biber line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script/biber line 13.

This error occurs with TeXLive with this installer: install-tl-20240513
On the other hand, this one runs okay: install-tl-20240213
I am running this on: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009

the errors are in the biber cache /tmp/par-6a6f736875612e68796b6573/ what happens if you delete that and let it make a new cache?

Thanks for the suggestion @DavidCarlisle. I did this: rm -rf /tmp/par-6a6f736875612e68796b6573/, but unfortunately I still get the same error message.

sorry I can't help then I just did a tlmgr update this morning on linux and biber works for me, but with a different perl perhaps, I have: This is perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Which version of biber? Which perl?

I'm not sure about the biber version. biber version: 2.19 is the one that works from the 20240213 TeX Live installer. When I try to check the version (biber --version) with the 20240513 biber, I get the same error message.
I have tried with a few different versions of perl, and perhaps this is part of the problem. I installed TeX Live in a shell where perl points to v5.32.1. I have modified the $PATH to point to v5.16.3 and v5.36.3, and biber still dies with the same error message. Perhaps the biber executable has saved the location of perl and doesn't pull it from $PATH?

If you are using biber from TL, your perl version is irrelevant as biber includes its own perl.

I was getting the above error when using CentOS 7, which is quite old at this point. When I switch to Red Hat 8, biber runs okay.
This is the specific Red Hat version I'm using now: Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.9 (Ootpa)
